# Title of a widow?

Tags: british-english, titles

I have to book a flight for my grandma who was married and became a widow. She still has to get a new ID but I want to book the flight asap. How do I write her title? Miss, misses,  or?

Comment: I don't think any title would have any influence on booking. Just type her printed name in her passport (for international flight) or in her ID (for domestic flight). Just don't choose titles for a male.

Comment: In my experience they bother me for every little detail. But the question remain what the title of a widow would be.

Comment: What kind of every little detail can you have? I mean, you have your passport. It shows your name. Countries have different standards to put whatever title before any name. I don't think there are many titles used in a passport. Believe me. I used to fly around the world using my mileage.

Comment: I agree with you. But the company I fly with can be a nuisance.

Comment: In this case, matching the relevant ID document is most important.

Comment: We don't have the ID yet and that will be in a foreign language. Never had a problem with this before but neither did I fly with a widow before. But looking at the answer it doesn't seem a strict title.

Comment: Definitely Mrs for a widow. Many divorced women continue to use their marital surname and the title 'Mrs'. Widowed women do that almost exclusively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two questions here: what is the "proper" title for a widow, and will the airline care?

1. For the first, I'd go with whatever is more comfortable for your grandma (I would guess Mrs. if she was happily married).
2. For the second question, I think that either Miss or Mrs is perfectly acceptable to them. The title is more about how people should address her; unlike her name, it's not a "legal" descriptor.

Comment: I wouldn't address an elderly woman as *Miss*, unless she were a spinster. Most women over the age of about 60 are happy to retain their title of Mrs, and it is the understood proper etiquette in the UK. However whilst a married woman, traditionally was always addressed by her husband's initials - - e.g.on an envelope  as Mrs G(eorge) Walters,  in widowhood it was always customary to write Mrs M(ary) Walters. However nowadays it would be considered by many inappropriate to call a woman by her husband's name. Some women prefer Ms, whether they be married, divorced, widowed or single.

Comment: I agree with WS2. *Miss* would definitely be wrong, but even then it is unlikely that anyone (except the lady in question) would care.

Answer (score 4):

Her title should be ***whatever she wants it to be*** -- Mrs, Ms, Miss, Mx, Mme, Mlle, Senora (sorry, not sure of the abbreviation), -- ***whatever she chooses.***.

To address propriety: There is absolutely no reason, or convention, for the *title* of a widow to change from whatever title she used pre-widowhood. And there never was. If she was Mrs before, she is Mrs now, unless she decide otherwise. Whatever it is, if it is her choice, it is OK.

Rathony is correct.  The airport people don't care.  Even if she chooses to call herself Lady, or Princess, they are not going to ask for a copy of Debrett's or the Alamanch de Gotha to verify that she is entitled (oops, pun).

As for the *form* of her name -- i.e., Mrs John Smith becomes Mrs Mary Smith because her husband died -- that used to be a social convention, but now no one worth knowing is going to raise an eyebrow one way or the other -- except the airport people if the name on her ticket does not match exactly the name on her ID.

Comment: FYI, Sra. is short for "señora" and Srta. for "señorita".

Answer (score 2):

I think '**Ms**' is the best choice. It is marriage-neutral, so no matter she was married and is now a widow.

Comment: Do you really think immigration officers would ask you if you are married, if you are divorced or if you are widowed in any international airport? They don't care as long as the name and sex match your picture in the passport.

Comment: @Rathony - Yes, you are correct. But the question is how a widow should be titled, regardless of whether the immigration officers will care for her marital status or not. I have tried to answer that question.